# Как организовать хранение настроек по конкретному пути?

Tags: c#, windows-service

Введение: жило-было WinForms-приложение, работающее по принципу “включил и забыл”. Из GUI кнопки старт/стоп и окно с настройками.  Настройки хранятся через settings.settings. Поступает задача – запускать его как службу. Ок, служба создает экземпляр главной формы, OnStart/OnStop есть, все работает.

Что делать с настройками? Доступа к GUI из службы нет, нужен внешний файл. Settings.settings не подходят, т.к. пишут в xml только измененные настройки. Можно, конечно, делать фиктивное переприсваивание value=value, но это как-то костыль,  да лезть за ними в AppData не очень удобно. Использовать внешний txt/ini - нужно руками писать парсинг/запись и, пять же, чтобы не лезть за ним в System32, зашивать путь к файлу непосредственно в код.

Собственно, вопрос: есть ли готовые способы/решения, позволяющие взаимодействовать с файлом настроек, лежащим по конкретному пути.

P.S. Как я понимаю, при запуске службы ей никакие параметры передать нельзя? Давай на входе путь к конфигу было бы неплохо

Comment: app.config? <appsetting>?

Comment: Окей, а с чьими правами запускается служба? Того же юзера, или администратора?